# Parabolic collector and Angle of incidence

Tags: solar-system

Would a static non movable parabolic solar collector always focus the light hitting such collector to the same position of its focus?..

Or it's focal position would vary depending on where the sun is hitting the collector?

Comment: [Parabolic mirrors only bring on-axis light to a single point of focus](https://slittlefair.staff.shef.ac.uk/teaching/phy217/lectures/telescopes/l07/) and [Off-Axis Parabolic Mirror Selection Guide](https://www.edmundoptics.co.uk/knowledge-center/application-notes/optics/off-axis-parabolic-mirror-selection-guide/) may be of interest?